# How do I get my mic working with streaming?

Tags: sound, webcam, vlc, microphone, streaming

I'm able to stream from my computer and watch the stream on a local vlc using the following command:

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 :v4l2-standard= :inputlave=alsa://hw:0,0 :live-caching=300 :sout="#transcode{vcodec=WMV2,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=wma2,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{dst=:8080/stream.wmv}"
```

The problem is that I can't hear sound. The sound would come through my webcam.

I've done aplay --list-devices but do not see my Webcam (usb) there:

```
michaeljwjr@michaeljwjr-desk:~$ aplay --list-devices
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: ALC889 Analog [ALC889 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 1: ALC889 Digital [ALC889 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

However when I did lsusb I did see my Webcam: 
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:0766 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam VX-800